# Keep calling a callback until a particular value is recieved through the callback

Tags: c++, callback

I have a callback function that provides some data.

```
callback([](int check) {
});
```

I want to keep calling this callback function until the returned value of `check` is 0. How can I do it? The callback function takes some time to send the data. If I use a loop normally, it is calling the callback multiple times while I am waiting for the result of the first callback.

Comment: `std::async`? You could then await the response in every iteration of the loop. Might be really heavy creating a new async every iteration, but potentially offset by your data transfer time. I'm sure someone who knows more about this can provide a cleaner answer.

Comment: **You** want to keep calling it, or you want it to be called—by what?  It matters a lot whether you’re the author of `callback` here.

Comment: I am not the author of the callback. I want to call it until the returned value of the check is 0. @DavisHerring

Comment: @KaziSohan: So… you want to block each call to `callback` until the previous callback has happened, so that you know whether the argument was 0?

Comment: Yes. You are right. @DavisHerring

Comment: @KaziSohan your description does not make sense given the code you have shown. Can you please provide a better [mcve] demonstrating what you really want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `callback` performs the callback **synchronously** (and assuming it accepts any **callable**), you can just use a capture:

```
bool go;
do callback([&go](int check) {go=check;}); while(go);
```

Alternatively, if `callback` performs the callback in another thread, you can use a `std::promise` to “undo” the **concurrency**:

```
while([] {
    std::promise<bool> p;
    callback([&p](int check) {p.set_value(check);});
    return p.get_future().get();
  }());
```

The wrapper lambda here lets us avoid declaring `go` again just to assign to it normally.

Comment: Thanks, @DavisHerring